# Reading Xml file from Server in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have a C# program that reads an XML file content from the server in this way:

```
public string ReadFileContent()
    {
        string str = "";

        System.Net.HttpWebRequest req = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(HttpPath);
        System.Net.HttpWebResponse response = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        System.IO.Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        System.IO.StreamReader readStream = new System.IO.StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        str = readStream.ReadToEnd();
        response.Close();

        return str;
    }
```

and every week i change the data in this xml file manually in the server
but sometimes the server returns previous data not the current data at xml file, in some computers this problem appears, anyone know why this happen?

Comment: I'd suggest looking at your server caching configuration - its probably serving up stale data because its configured with a long period cache. Without further info on what server you are using (IIS, Apache etc) there is little more we can do.

Comment: Maybe some users are caching contents.

Comment: We'd need to know more about the web-server, perhaps it's a caching mechanism gone awry?  Which web-server are you using?  IIS?  What's the timestamp on the files on the server?  Can you modify the file in notepad or similar to bump the timestamp and see if that helps?

Comment: Thanks everybody, it was solved